# html align element relative to parent that has a width

Tags: html, css, css-float

given the html below. without changing any properties of the main element, how can i make the html element with id left/right be aligned to the left/right of the main element?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      main {
        width: 400px;
        margin: auto;
        border: 5px solid green;
        text-align: center;
      }
      #left {
        border: 5px solid red;
      }
      #right {
        border: 5px solid blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <span id="left">left</span>
      <span id="right">right</span>
      <div>content below left and right</div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

using `float: left` (or right) does align the elements, but it affects how other elements are displayed relative to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use float left and right and then apply `clear: both;` to the following element/s.

Addition after comment: "Normal" content *floats*  next to floated elements, i.e. it's positioned at the left/right borders of the floated elements, as you obviously experienced when trying it. If you want the subsequent element/s to start *below* a floated element, you can add `clear: left` or `right` or `both` (try these options to see the effect).

```css
main {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}

#left {
  border: 5px solid red;
  float: left;
}

#right {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  float: right;
}
#right + div {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <span id="left">left</span>
    <span id="right">right</span>
    <div>content below left and right</div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you. that worked. could you add a short explanation why does it work?

Comment: I just added it.

Comment: from you words i understand that it is sufficient to use `div { clear: both; }` and that's it.

Comment: Yes, it is, but the way I wrote it limits it to *subsequent*  `div` elements of `#right`. Still more precise (i.e. limited to *one*  particular element) would be to use a class or ID on the first div after `#right` and use that as a selector for the CSS rule which contains `clear: both`. (I tried to *not* change the HTML code in your question, but it would be better)

Answer (score 0):

You can also play with `text-align` and keep your elements as inline elements

```css
main {
  width: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 5px solid green;
  text-align: justify;
}
main * {
  display: inline-block;
}
main div {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

#left {
  border: 5px solid red;
}

#right {
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <span id="left">left</span>
  <span id="right">right</span>
  <div>content below left and right</div>
</main>
```